# react-native-debugger not connecting to application while running

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-debugger

I have a react mobile application running on EXPO and am currently testing on my android mobile device. I've installed the React-Native-Debugger and have it running on port 19001. After shaking my device and turning on JS debugging, I see no change in the screen. At that point is there supposed to be a connection? I've attached some log I'm seeing although I'm uncertain if they are related. Any advice on steps I'm missing? Based on the docs I was following here, I assumed the debugger would just connect: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/debugging/

```
Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).
at http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4.js:4:234 in <unknown>
at http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4.js:4:641 in <unknown>
```

````
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1137:12)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._explodedSourceMapForURL (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1088:35)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1039:26)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:443:7)
Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4 from /Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1137:12)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Server._explodedSourceMapForURL (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1088:35)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at Server._symbolicate (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1039:26)
    at Server._processRequest (/Users/davionwilliams/smart-user-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:443:7)
Android Running app on BE2028 ```
````